# Is there any Fluent NHibernate book?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

Taking into consideration that Fluent NHibernate has been available for some time I thought that there would be a book available already so i search in amazon and in google but there is no books for fluent nhiberanet. Am i right or book already exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate is a mapping strategy for NHibernate, it is not large enough to justify a book to itself. Everything outside of mapping is exactly the same as NHibernate (in fact, it *is* NHibernate).

The best thing you can do is study the existing NHibernate material out there (such as the [Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book) suggested by [Nicholas Murray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913187/is-there-any-fluent-nhibernate-book/3914870#3914870)), and then use the Fluent NHibernate [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki) to read up on the new things that FNH brings to the table.

Answer (score 7):

You should consider purchasing the new NHibernate 3.0 [Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book) as Fluent NHibernate is [referenced](https://www.packtpub.com/toc/nhibernate-30-cookbook-table-contents) throughout the book.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a good book on NHibernate itself since it is big but the idea behind Fluent NHibernate is that with a few examples you could pick it up so that you should not need a book.

This is the beauty of **fluent API**.